# React: Children does not update when parent's value change

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I got it with Amire's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69822274/react-children-does-not-update-when-parents-value-change#comment123420984_69822274)

See more in Amirhe's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69842654/14745811)

In closing, key must be an object.

---

I have an **array** in **store**:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    value: 'value 1',
  },
]
```

In **parent**, I call it from **store**

And then, I  transmit data to **Child**:

```
function Parent({array}){
  return
    <Child
      key={array}
      items={array}
    />
}
```

When I update **array**, `delete` or `add` item, then I `get` data again from backend to update, the prop in **Child** will be update.
E.g:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    value: 'value 1',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value: 'value 2',
  },
]
```

But if I `update`:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    value: 'value 1',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value: 'value update',
  },
]
```

prop in parent is **updated**, but in child is **not**.

My ENG is not good but I wish that everyone will understand clearly my main idea.

Comment: Please provide more details and code

Comment: Change `key={JSON.stringify(tmpList)}`, but if you can add more details I can suggest better action to be taken.

Comment: Seems that you mutate restList array instead of replace it to new one, when you changed it

Comment: if `propTable` is a state, use setSate. remove push

Comment: Sorry I updated. I hope the problem will be clearer

Comment: Regardless of the answer, I definitely think the `key` should NOT be set to the array. Key should be a unique string (or if it's not dynamically generated like a list item, you don't even need it) to identify that particular element across updates, and you've given it the array, which is an object. I think you should remove it regardless of the problem.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu tks you. I got it.

Comment: @Amirhe so can you give me a better way? thank u so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As react doc [says](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys),

> A “key” is a special string attribute you need to include when creating lists of elements.
> The best way to pick a key is to use a string that uniquely identifies a list item among its siblings.

When you pass an array as a string representation to component key, (it most probably) gets converted to a string. meaning it will call the `.toString` method.

Let's see what [`Array.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) method do with your given array

```js
const state = [
  { id: 1, value: 'value 1' },
  { id: 2, value: 'value 2' },
]

state.toString() // '[object Object],[object Object]'

const newState = [
  { id: 1, value: 'value 1' },
  { id: 5, value: 'value 5 ⭐' },
]
newState.toString() // '[object Object],[object Object]'
JSON.stingify(newState) // '[{"id":1,"value":"value 1"},{"id":5,"value":"value 5 ⭐"}]'
```

As you see your object will be converted to `'[object Object]'` and get joined by `,`. this makes it clear why adding and deleting make triggers render but changing doesn't.

The better way to achieve this is to generate a deterministic hash to make it crystal clear for the react that mutation (changing) must trigger render. I provide a bunch of examples and you can pick what fits you.

```
// if id will change in your patches
key={array.map(item => item.id).join('-')}

// if id won't changes but title gets updated
// This is the probably the same as JSON.stringify
key={array.map(item => item.id+item.title).join('-')}

// this example is not recommended but give you more insight
// I used combination of index and item id
key={array.map((item, idx) => `${idx}.${item.id}`).join(' ')}
// if your only the title changes this will not cause re-render
```

[in-depth explanation on the negative impacts of using an index as a key.](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318)

If I suppose to do this I would probably remove the extra child layer and map over data directly in jsx.

```
function Parent({array}){
  return array && array.map(item => (
    <InnerChildComponent
      key={'get proper key from above list fit your case based on item'}
      items={item}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: yes. I got it. thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Reference to your array isn't changing, so React is doing a shallow comparison and decide that it doesn't need to re-render. Either implement `shouldComponentUpdate` logic yourself to explicitly check the elements of the array too, or just create a new array with the elements that you want and pass that to the component.

Comment: sorry. I updated the question. I hope the problem will be clearer.